# decode GPS coordinate from USB GPS

Tags: python, gps, serial-port, nmea

I have GPS/GLONASS U-BLOX 7. When I run the U-Center application it can show me the Latitude and Longitude. However, I need to decode this value from the serial port (add them in python code).
My problem I could not find how the docking works. U-Center app is receiving these data. When I search for NMEA commands, it seems some data are missing. But I was wondering how U-Center is decoding the Lat and Long.

Anybody has an idea?

Here is the output of of my GPS data from serial port:

```
08:58:08  $GPRMC,085808.00,V,,,,,,,211217,,,N*76    
08:58:08  $GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30  
08:58:08  $GPGGA,085808.00,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*6B  
08:58:08  $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30  
08:58:08  $GPGSV,3,1,10,03,83,342,,09,14,211,,11,35,165,,12,02,352,*78  
08:58:08  $GPGSV,3,2,10,14,21,046,,17,42,279,,19,33,304,,22,67,073,*7B
08:58:08  $GPGSV,3,3,10,23,46,197,,32,01,042,*72
08:58:08  $GPGLL,,,,,085808.00,V,N*47
08:58:09  $GPRMC,085809.00,V,,,,,,,211217,,,N*77
08:58:09  $GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30
08:58:09  $GPGGA,085809.00,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*6A
08:58:09  $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30
08:58:09  $GPGSV,3,1,10,03,83,342,,09,14,211,,11,35,165,,12,02,352,*78
08:58:09  $GPGSV,3,2,10,14,21,046,,17,42,279,13,19,33,304,,22,67,073,*79   
08:58:09  $GPGSV,3,3,10,23,46,197,,32,01,042,*72   
08:58:09  $GPGLL,,,,,085809.00,V,N*46   
08:58:10  $GPRMC,085810.00,V,,,,,,,211217,,,N*7F   
08:58:10  $GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30   
08:58:10  $GPGGA,085810.00,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*62  
08:58:10  $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30    
08:58:10  $GPGSV,3,1,10,03,83,342,,09,14,211,,11,35,165,,12,02,352,*78    
08:58:10  $GPGSV,3,2,10,14,21,046,,17,42,279,,19,33,304,,22,67,073,*7B     
08:58:10  $GPGSV,3,3,10,23,46,197,,32,01,042,*72     
08:58:10  $GPGLL,,,,,085810.00,V,N*4E    
08:58:11  $GPRMC,085811.00,V,,,,,,,211217,,,N*7E    
08:58:11  $GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30    
08:58:11  $GPGGA,085811.00,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*63     
08:58:11  $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30    
08:58:11  $GPGSV,3,1,10,03,83,342,,09,14,211,,11,35,165,,12,02,352,*78    
08:58:11  $GPGSV,3,2,10,14,21,046,,17,42,279,17,19,33,304,,22,67,073,*7D  
08:58:11  $GPGSV,3,3,10,23,46,197,,32,01,042,*72    
08:58:11  $GPGLL,,,,,085811.00,V,N*4F     
08:58:12  $GPRMC,085812.00,V,,,,,,,211217,,,N*7D     
08:58:12  $GPVTG,,,,,,,,,N*30     
08:58:12  $GPGGA,085812.00,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*60    
08:58:12  $GPGSA,A,1,,,,,,,,,,,,,99.99,99.99,99.99*30    
08:58:12  $GPGSV,3,1,10,03,83,344,,09,14,211,,11,35,165,,12,02,352,*7E     
08:58:12  $GPGSV,3,2,10,14,21,046,,17,42,279,,19,33,304,,22,67,073,*7B   
08:58:12  $GPGSV,3,3,10,23,46,197,,32,01,042,*72       
08:58:12  $GPGLL,,,,,085812.00,V,N*4C    
08:58:13  $GPRMC,085813.00,V,,,,,,,211217,,,N*7C
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the following NMEA sentences in your log:

- RMC
- VTG
- GGA
- GSV
- GLL

*(The GP letters in front of the tags is the talker ID and is not relevant here.)*

VTG is a sentence containing speed and course and is not relevant here. GSV shows the number of satellites in view and can't be used to extract position.

So you can choose between RMC, GGA and GLL when you want to find the longitude and latitude. They typically have the following format:

**[RMC](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RMC):**

```
$GPRMC,123519,A,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,022.4,084.4,230394,003.1,W*6A

Where:
     RMC          Recommended Minimum sentence C
     123519       Fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC
     A            Status A=active or V=Void.
     4807.038,N   Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N
     01131.000,E  Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E
     022.4        Speed over the ground in knots
     084.4        Track angle in degrees True
     230394       Date - 23rd of March 1994
     003.1,W      Magnetic Variation
     *6A          The checksum data, always begins with *
```

If we match the definition with one of your sentences:

`$GPRMC,085808.00,V,,,,,,,211217,,,N*76`

we can see that fix was taken at 08:58 UTC, but the signal is now invalid (void). The fields are empty because you don't have a fix. If you did have a fix you would see similar numbers as in the definition.

**[GGA](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GGA):**

```
 $GPGGA,123519,4807.038,N,01131.000,E,1,08,0.9,545.4,M,46.9,M,,*47

Where:
     GGA          Global Positioning System Fix Data
     123519       Fix taken at 12:35:19 UTC
     4807.038,N   Latitude 48 deg 07.038' N
     01131.000,E  Longitude 11 deg 31.000' E
     1            Fix quality: 0 = invalid
                               1 = GPS fix (SPS)
                               2 = DGPS fix
                               3 = PPS fix
                   4 = Real Time Kinematic
                   5 = Float RTK
                               6 = estimated (dead reckoning) (2.3 feature)
                   7 = Manual input mode
                   8 = Simulation mode
     08           Number of satellites being tracked
     0.9          Horizontal dilution of position
     545.4,M      Altitude, Meters, above mean sea level
     46.9,M       Height of geoid (mean sea level) above WGS84
                      ellipsoid
     (empty field) time in seconds since last DGPS update
     (empty field) DGPS station ID number
     *47          the checksum data, always begins with *
```

If we match the definition with one of your sentences:

`$GPGGA,085808.00,,,,,0,00,99.99,,,,,,*6B`

we can see that the fix quality is 0 and you have no fix. The GPS unit sends blank values in the longitude and latitude fields.

**[GLL](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#GLL):**

```
  $GPGLL,4916.45,N,12311.12,W,225444,A,*1D

Where:
     GLL          Geographic position, Latitude and Longitude
     4916.46,N    Latitude 49 deg. 16.45 min. North
     12311.12,W   Longitude 123 deg. 11.12 min. West
     225444       Fix taken at 22:54:44 UTC
     A            Data Active or V (void)
     *iD          checksum data
```

If we match the definition with one of your sentences:

`$GPGLL,,,,,085808.00,V,N*47`

This sentence is also *void*, meaning no longitude or latitude is sent.

---

So when you start receiving proper data the log will look more like the definitions I listed. The data active flags will switch from *V* to *A* and the fields will have values rather than being empty. You probably have to go outside and get a good signal for this to happen. For extracting data you have to choose between either the RMC, GGA or GLL sentences: they all contain what you are looking for.

For actually parsing the data in Python you can use a library such as [pynmea2](https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2), [micropyGPS](https://github.com/inmcm/micropyGPS) or something similar. Or you could write the logic yourself.

Should be quite simple to write the logic yourself. Just split the telegram with `,` as split character. The last field also has to be split with `*` to separate field and checksum.

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your complete explanation. Now i exactly learned how everything works.
And , yes once I moved in clear space, i could get the complete values, and I have done the coding in python used GPSD lib.
here is great example for doing that : http://www.danmandle.com/blog/getting-gpsd-to-work-with-python/

Answer (score 0):

Well, after testing more, i found out at a point of a time it recieve the GPGLL like this: 
$GPGLL,4908.59700,N,00912.84108,E,122829.00,A,A*6A
which using the NMEA format I could extract my Lat and Lon, however still i do not know how U-Center was getting this value, but I assume they were showing the last received location.
Still if anybody has any idea, would be much appreciated if you share it with me. 
thanks